# When should you explicitly call things like Close() and Dispose() on VB.Net SqlConnections, SqlCommands, etc.?

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection, idisposable, sqlconnection

Take code like this:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable("Table")
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(pQuery, pCon)

    sda.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = pCommandTimeout
    sda.Fill(dt)
    sda.Dispose()

    Return dt
```

and:

```
    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(DBValues.m_sDBString)
    myconnection.Open()

    Try
        Dim com As New SqlCommand(cmd, myconnection)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        com.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        If myconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            myconnection.Close()
            myconnection.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
```

When is it getting excessive to explicity call things like Close() and Dispose()?  Because apparently the GC handles this internally most of the time, but not all the time (?).  So far I haven't really seen somebody put down a very clear and unambiguous explanation on how to distinguish between when this is excessive and when it isn't, or what the difference is between doing this explicitly and just letting the GC handle it.  Could somebody explain this?  Thanks!

Comment: Use the `Using` statement which also closes connections. It will also ensure that the object gets disposed, even on error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't doing anything more complicated than what's in the example, then it is probably excessive.

You could use the `using` keyword to make things simpler. It automates the calling of the `Dispose` method of objects from classes that implement `IDisposable`.

[Relevant documentation on the `using` keyword, for VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Also note that the `Dispose` method of `SqlConnection` calls its `Close` method too (running the same state validation you do in your code).

Notice that there are situations where you might have to call `Dispose` manually instead of going with `using`. For example, you might want to use a data reader in more than one context, so using `using` in either of them may not be desired. You'll know when you're in one of these situations, and then calling `Dispose` yourself won't be overkill. But only then.

Comment: You mean basically if I don't need to keep the object live for a little while, but may need to use it again later?

Comment: When you use the `using` keyword, the object get's its `Dispose` method called as soon as the `using` block ends. If you try to use the object after the block, it'll already have release any unmanaged resources. Think about that. You should either limit the usage of the object to the `using` block, or not use `using` and call `Dispose` yourself when you think the time's right for that.

Comment: So Dispose should be called if and only if a using block is not used?

Comment: Yes, because if you are using a `using` block, the runtime will try to call it again after the block. And it's generally an error to try to dispose of the same object twice.